# Move a paragraph up or down in pages

Tags: ms-office, pages

In MS-Word I could move a whole paragraph up/down within the text using Shift-Alt-Up or -Down keys. No need to highlight anything, Ms-word already knows which paragraph the cursor is in. Just have the cursor somewhere in the paragraph you want to bump up or down the page, and one Shift-Alt-Down keypress does it. It auto-repeats too, so it's fast and worked like a dream in text, lists or outlines, ideal for re-ordering my thoughts.

In Pages I have to carefully highlight the paragraph, then drag it (or cut and paste), is there another way? There is no macro facility, sadly.

(August 2023) I see that the Apple App Notes now has exactly this function in the Format menu:  Format/'Move List Item': the
control-command-up-arrow or control-command-down-arrow keys move the current paragraph or list-item up or down. It can easily be repeated.
For me, an important feature is that this is a keystroke function, my fingers have learned it, and I don't have to break concentration to check if I'm using the mouse or mousepad to drag etc.

Comment: (Edit) added mention of Notes app having this 'Move List Item' function

Answer (score 1):

You can select a paragraph and right-click on it and drag it to another location. Sometimes a right-click will open a pop-up menu but just let go of right click and try again. I don't know how to turn off popup.

Comment: OK yes I understand that I can L-click-drag to move any highlighted text, but highlighting a paragraph with shift-L-click-drag takes significant concentration and hand-eye focus - although the computer already knows what paragraph the cursor is in. MS-word Shift-Alt-UP or -Down selects the whole paragraph automatically and moves it past the adjacent paragraph in one keypress, and it supports auto-repeat so you can quickly slip chunks of text up and down the doc without having to select anything first. I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: All you have to do in Pages to select a paragraph is to left-click at the first of the paragraph and while holding the left-click drag the mouse.  Or you can double-click in the paragraph. No key strokes are required to select a paragraph in Pages.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance on text selection - that is only part of the story. As I stated, the paragraph moves up and down without any need to align it. This means that no fine hand-eye coordination is needed, very important.